# Is it "Proper" for a Behavior to Act as a View Model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, attachedbehaviors

Recently, in a WPF project, I created an attached behavior for a third party control in order to make it more MVVM-friendly.  My initial approach was to bind it to the view model, which in turn was bound to other controls.  However, after thinking about it, I realized that I could reduce the overall amount of code if I simply made the Behavior itself the data context for some of the other controls.  I tried it, and it works fine.  While this approach seems unconventional to me, I honestly can't think of any real objection to it.  So does this still conform to MVVM etiquette?  Any opinions?

Comment: Attached Behaviors are generally meant to be reusable and are a "view concern". Views shouldn't contain any presentation logic, that's what ViewModel is for. When you put ViewModel responsibilities into an attached behavior, it's not reusable anymore as it's tied to a specific application (since it uses this applications ViewModel). Except if you make it very generic and reference your context as `object`

Comment: Thanks, I think you put it very nicely.